# Extract bits in C

Tags: c, extract

I am a bit new to C-programming and I am a bit stuck with this question:

Assume that you have a C program with signed integer (int) variables x, y, and z. All
variables contain some arbitrary values. Write a C-statement that extracts the bits with
index 17 to 13 from x and places them as the least significant bits in z, and extracts the
least 3 significant bits of y and places them in the bits with index 7 to 5 in z. No other
bits of z should be changed, besides the 8 bits that were extracted from x and y. Note
that the bit index 0 is the least significant bit. Your answer should contain one single C
statement together with short notes of what the different parts of the statement do.

I understand that extracting is the same thing as shifting if I am not wrong.

But could someone please give me some hints on how to tackle this question?

Thanks, all help will be appriciated!

Comment: No, extracting is *not* the same as shifting.

Comment: The assignment has less to do with C and more to do with you understanding basic bit-fiddling. Things you need to learn about is the bitwise and operation, the bitwise or operation and the bitwise shift (left and right) operations. Also, try to do it all on paper first, to get it right there. And a last hint, try to do the operations one at a time, and when you have gotten it right *then* try to make it into a single expression (one step at a time).

Comment: I won't do it for you, but look at bitwise AND `&` and bitwise OR `|` operators for bit extraction, and shifting to move them around.

Comment: Hint: you need shifting (`<<` and `>>` oprators), masking (`&` operator) and the `|` operator.

Comment: Imagine an 8-bit system: 0101 1001
Now take the bitwise &:
0101 1001 & 0000 1111  -->  0000 1001

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extract the bits from x:

```
int b = x & 0x3E000;  /* x AND (...) 0011 1110 0000 0000 0000*/
```

Shift the extracted bits:

```
b = b >> 13; /* 13 bits to the right, so that they land up starting on the first position */
```

Clean the bits from z:

```
z &= 0xFFFFFFE0; /* z AND 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 0000 */
```

Apply the bits to z:

```
z |= b;
```

Extract the bits from y:

```
b = y & 0x3; /* y AND (...) 0000 0111 */
```

Shift the extracted bits:

```
b = b << 5; /* move them 5 bits to the left so that they end up starting on position 5 */
```

Clear the bits from z:

```
z &= 0xFFFFFF1F; /* z AND 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0001 1111 */
```

Apply the bits to z:

```
z |= b;
```

You can now combine the "clearings" into a single operation:

```
z &= 0xFFFFFF00; /* z AND 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000 */
```

All in a single statement:

```
z = (z & 0xFFFFFF00) | ((y & 0x3) << 5) | ((x & 0x3E000) >> 13);
```

This works for 32-bits integers, or `int32_t` (C99 and beyond).
With 64-bits integers (`int64_t`), you just have to use 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00 as a "clearing mask".

If you're using vanilla `int` variables, get the size in bits using the following:

```
printf("int has %ud bits\n", sizeof(int) * 8);
```

`sizeof()` returns the size in bytes of an integer, and then you multiply that result by 8 (bits per byte in 99.999% of cases)to get the size in bits of your integer, and therefore the size of the masks you have to apply.

In general:

- Extract bits by applying an AND mask, with every bit set to 0, except those you want to extract, which you will set to 1. The reason is that 0 AND X = 0, but 1 AND X = X.
- Shift bits to the position you need them to be.
- Clear bits by applying an AND mask, with every bit set to 1, except those you want to clear, which you will set to 0. The reason is the same as above.
- Apply bits by using an OR operation. You must ensure that the bits you do want to modify on the destination are set to 0, and that those which you do NOT want to modify on the origin are set to 0. The reason for that is that 1 OR X = 1, but 0 OR X = X.

Comment: OP is asking for some hints, not for a complete solution :)

Comment: Oops! Once again, I sinned of not reading a question carefully enough. I guess, in my defense, that one can say that "some hints" are indeed contained in a complete solution. I hope I haven't spoiled OP.

Comment: Anyway nice answer ;)

Comment: No, thats ok Adrien. But thanks a lot, you really saved my time dude :D

Comment: b = y & 0x3; /* y AND (...) 0000 0111 */  isnt it supposed to be 0x7 instead of 0x3?

Comment: @Adrien Please check your numbers, Marcus is right. `0x3` is not `0b01110000`, it is `0b00110000`.